# CMake finds incorrect headers for python libs 3.8 under 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python, cmake

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and a project using boost python is no longer building.

The issue lies in the following CMake command:

```
find_package(PythonLibs 3)
```

which sets `${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to `/usr/include/python3.6m`. The problem is, there is no `libpython3.6-dev` in 20.4 and thus no headers at that location. I do have `libpython3.8-dev` however.

Even if I change the above to `find_package(PythonLibs 3.8)`, I get

```
[cmake] Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (Required is at least version "3.8")
```

with same include dirs as before.

I can manually `set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/include/python3.8)` and everything builds just fine, so seems it's really just the `find_package` behaving unexpectedly. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I realized that `find_package(PythonLibs)` is [deprecated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPythonLibs.html) since CMake 3.12 (coincides with my upgrade to 20.04). Using `find_package(Python 3.8 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)` instead finds the correct headers.